# What do the dots and pluses mean when OpenSSL generates keys?

Tags: openssl

When OpenSSL generates keys you'll always see a series of periods/dots (`.`) and pluses (`+`).

`openssl dhparam -text -noout -outform PEM -5 2048`

> ............+........+...................................................................................................................................................................+..........................+......+......+..........................................................................................................................................................................................+....................................................................................................................................................................+..............................................................................................................................+.............................................................................................................................+.......+............................................................................................................................+..+.......................................................+....................................................................................................................................+..................................+...........................................................+...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................+.+...................................................................................................+................................................................................................+.....+....+.................+.......................................................+.............................................................................................+...............................................................................................................................................................+................+....................................................+....................................................................................+...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................+.......................................................................+......................................................................................................................................................................................................................+............................................................+...........................................................................+.............................................................+.......................................+....................................................................................+............................................................................................................................................................+..................+...........................................................+.......................................................................................+.....................................................................................................................+...............................................................................................+.............................+.....................................+..................+...........................................................................................................+...........................................+...+.............................................................................................................................................................................+....................................................+............+.............................................................................................................................................................+.....................................+.....+.........................+...........................................................+..........................................................................................+............................................................................................................................................+.................................................+..........................................................................................+.......................+..........................................................................................+......................................................................................................................................................................................+.................................................................................................+...........................................................+.............................................................................................................................+......................+.............................................................................................................................+........................................+..........................................................................+..............................................+............................................................+...+.................................................................................+............................................+................+..........+.........+.....................................+...........................................+..........................................................................................................+........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................+...........................................................................+..........................+..................................+...........................................................+................................................................................+..+.........................+..................................................................................................................................+........................+.......................................................+..........................................................................................+..........................................+.+...................................................+............................................................................................................+.........................................................................................................................................................................................................+.................................................................................................+....................+.......................................................................................................................+...............................+............................................................................+...............................+....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................+.........................................+.....................+........................................................................+.....................+..........+...............................................................+...........+...............................+....++*++*

What do they mean?

Comment: I too was curious so I opened up the code and did some poking around. I found this information by looking at the openssl source code under apps/dhparam.c static int MS_CALLBACK dh_cb(int p, int n, BN_GENCB *cb) { char c = '*'; if (p == 0) c = '.'; if (p == 1) c = '+'; if (p == 2) c = '*'; if (p == 3) c = '\n'; ... Which is used to a callback to BN_GENCB_set(&cb, dh_cb, bio_err); Which is defined in crypto/bn/bn.h /* Macro to populate a BN_GENCB structure with a "new"-style callback */ # define BN_GENCB_set(gencb, callback, cb_arg) { \ BN_GENCB *tmp_gencb = (gencb); \ tmp_gencb->ver = 2; \ tmp_

Answer (score 77, accepted):

When computing DHPARAM you will get these as the output while computing [Diffie Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) parameters:

```
. : A potential prime number was generated.
+ : Number is being tested for primality.
* : A prime number was found.
```

References:

- source code: [`dh_cb` function in `dhparam.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6f0ac0e2f27d9240516edb9a23b7863e7ad02898/apps/dhparam.c#L362)
- man page: [`dhparam`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dhparam.html)

Comment: I'm curious: where did you get this information? I don't doubt it's correct, but I haven't been able to find a manual page or other documentation about it. I did a Google search for `"A potential prime number was generated"` and found a blog that has the exact same verbatim information, so I assume it's quoted from *somewhere*, but I haven't found any official source (maybe source-code comments?).

Comment: The source can be found here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6f0ac0e2f27d9240516edb9a23b7863e7ad02898/apps/dhparam.c#L362

Answer (score 23):

In the context of Diffie-Hellman parameter generation, `.` means a potential prime has been generated. `+` means one iteration of the Miller-Rabin primality test have been passed. `*` means a prime has been found that satisfies one iteration of the Miller-Rabin primality test.

Under default conditions, for generating a prime with at least 1300 bits, two iterations of the Miller-Rabin primality test are done. That's why you see `++*++*` at the end. The first `+` means the prime *p* itself has passed one iteration of the Miller-Rabin primality test. The second `+` means the (*p*-1)/2 also has passed one iteration of the Miller-Rabin primality test. The first `*` indicates both *p* and (*p*-1)/2 has passed an iteration of the Miller-Rabin primality test.

Then both are retested again (since `BN_prime_checks_for_size(2048) == 2` for two iterations), so you see `++*` again.

Since *p* and (*p*-1)/2 passed both iterations of primality tests, the process stops and returns *p*.

So if you see one `+`, it means a candidate prime generated passed one iteration of the primality test but (*p*-1)/2 didn't. If you see `++*` but not `++*++*` it means both *p* and (*p*-1)/2 passed the first iteration of primality tests but one of them failed the second iteration (which in all likelihood, would never happen for 2048 bit keys and longer -- a cosmic ray flipping a bit during the calculation is more likely).

References:

- man page: `BN_GENCB_call`
- man page: `BN_is_prime_fasttest_ex`
- source code: [`BN_generate_prime_ex`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6f0ac0e2f27d9240516edb9a23b7863e7ad02898/crypto/bn/bn_prime.c#L147)
- source code: [`BN_prime_checks_for_size`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6f0ac0e2f27d9240516edb9a23b7863e7ad02898/include/openssl/bn.h#L118)